# Prove that $J_r(n) = n^r\prod_{p|n}\left(1− \frac{1}{p^r}\right)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

For $r ≥ 1$, let $J_r(n)$ be Jordan's totient function, i.e., the number of $r$-tuples of integers $a_j$ with $1 ≤ a_j ≤ n$ for $j = 1,\ldots,r$, and $(a_1,\ldots,a_r,n) = 1$. Prove that $$J_r(n) = n^r\prod_{p|n}\left(1− \frac{1}{p^r}\right).$$

Comment: This is Jacobi’s totient function. When r = 1 it coincides with Euler’s function ϕ. I think that the best thing is to prove that is moltiplicative and then compute but i'm not able to do it. Someone can help me please?

Comment: [Jordan's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function) function?

Comment: oh you're right my mistake sorry.. i'll edit it

Comment: Suppose $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ are all prime natural numbers that divide $n$.  Let $S$ be the set of all $r$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r)$ such that $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r\le n$.  Let $E_i$ be the set of $n$-tuples of positive integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r\le n$ such that each is divisible by $p_i$.   Calculate $\left|E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2}\cap \ldots \cap E_{i_s}\right|$.  Then use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to find $|S|-\left|E_1\cup E_2\cup\ldots \cup E_k\right|$.

Comment: Or you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to establish multiplicativity of $J_r$, and then you are left with calculating $J_r(p^\ell)$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Or you can show that $\sum_{d\mid n} J_r(d)=n^r$ and then apply the Moebius inversion formula.

Comment: And how would you calculate $J_r(p^l) $?

Comment: There are $(p^l)^r$ $r$-tuples with components between $1$ and $p^l$. Of those, $(p^{l-1})^r$ have all components divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f(n,d) = \# \{ (a_1,\ldots,a_r), a_j\le n,d| a_j\}$$
Then $$\# \{ (a_1,\ldots,a_r), a_j\le n, \gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_r,n)=1\}=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f(n,d)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)(n/d)^r$$

Answer (score 1):

*Let us prove that $J_k(n)=n^k \displaystyle\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^k}\right)$. We first prove it for $p^a$ for every $p$ prime and $a\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ by induction on k. $\,$ It follows for n by multiplicativity.

If $k=1$ 
The thesis is $J_1(p^a)=p^{a}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ 
$J_1(p^a)=$ #{$a_1$, such that $a_1\le p^a$ and gcd($a_1,p^a)=1\}=\phi(p^a)=p^{a}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ 
Let us suppose it is true for $k-1$, and let's demonstrate it for $k$: 
$J_k(p^a)=$ #{{$a_1$,…,$a_{k}\}$, such that $a_i\le p^a$ and gcd($a_1$,…,$a_{k},p^a)=1\}$. 
If gcd($a_1$,…,$a_{k-1},p^a)=1$, then $a_k$ can be every number in $\{1,…,p^a\}$
If gcd($a_1$,…,$a_{k-1},p^a)\not=1$, then $a_k\notin\{1p,2p…,p^{a-1}p\}$, so there are only $p^a-p^{a-1}$ options for $a_k$.
Therefore, $\begin{equation}J_k(p^a)={(p^a)}^{(k-1)}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{k-1}}\right)p^a+{(p^{a-1})}^{(k-1)}(p^a-p^{a-1})\\
\ ={(p^{ak})}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{k-1}}\right)+{(p^{a-1})}^{k}(p-1)\\
\  ={(p^{ak})}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{k-1}}\right)+{(p^{ak})}\left(\frac{p}{p^{k}}-\frac{1}{p^{k}}\right)\\
\ ={(p^{ak})}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{k-1}}+\frac{1}{p^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{p^{k}}\right)\\
\ = {(p^{ak})}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{k}}\right)\\
\end{equation}$.